# Template specialization when having a constant parameter

Tags: c++

I have class `Queue` that is implemented with templates, one parameter for the type and one constant parameter for the size of the queue.

```
  template <typename T, int N>
  class Queue
  {
     .....
     void enqueue(T x);
  }
```

I want to specialize the `enqueue` method, for the typename but I can not figure how to do this.

```
 template <typename T, int N>
 void Queue<Heap<struct infoNod>, N>::enqueue(Heap<struct infoNode> x)
 {}
```

---

For specializing the entire class I am not sure if i do it right:
in header:

```
 template <>
 class Queue<Heap<struct infoNode>, 100>
 {
    public:
       void enqueue(Heap<struct infNode> x);
 };
```

in cpp:

```
template <>
 void Queue<Heap<struct infoNod>, 100>::enqueue(Heap<struct infoNode> x) {}
```

errors:

```
Queue.cpp:77:6: error: template-id ‘enqueue<>’ for ‘void Queue<Heap<infoNod>, 100>::enqueue(Heap<infoNode>)’ does not match any template declaration
 void Queue<Heap<struct infoNod>, 100>::enqueue(Heap<struct infoNode> x)
      ^
Queue.cpp:77:78: note: saw 1 ‘template<>’, need 2 for specializing a member function template
 void Queue<Heap<struct infoNod>, 100>::enqueue(Heap<struct infoNode> x)
```

Comment: You can not specialize only a single member function, you need to specialize the whole class. Or create derivative class which inherits from `Queue<Heap<struct infoNod>, N>` and override only the `enqueue` function.

Comment: I tried to specialize the class, edited post.

Comment: I think you meant `Queue<struct infoNode, 100>`. Otherwise your enqueue function would accept a  `Queue<Heap<Heap<struct infoNode>>, 100>` as parameter

Comment: You need to show us the definition of the `enqueue` function that matches that error. And more importantly I think you need to read ["Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: On a side-note, passing the argument `x` by value might not be a good idea. Instead pass by constant reference, i.e. `Heap<infoNode> const& x` instead.

Comment: definition of enqueue: void enqueue(T x) / void enqueue(Heap<struct infoNode> x);

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a class template with a non-template `enqueue()` method, you can only partially specialize the whole class, not the individual method:

```
template <typename T, int N>
class Queue
{
    void enqueue(T x) { /* default implementation */ }
};

template<int N>
class Queue<Heap<InfoNode>, N>
{
   void enqueue(Heap<InfoNode> x) { /* specialized implementation */ }
};
```

Another alternative is not to specialize the whole `Queue` class but to make `enqueue()` delegate to a small helper class that will be specialized.

Comment: I specialized the Queue, and moved the implementation to the header. But if i specialize, can I access the methods and members from the unspecialized class. I have a method print in the unspecialized class, and i get error (error: ‘class Queue<Heap<infoNode>, 256>’ has no member named ‘print’)

Comment: @georgiana_e: The general and the specialized classes are unrelated, so you won't be able to call one's methods from another.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by extending the Queue class:

```
class QueueSpec: public Queue<Heap<struct infoNode>, SIZE >
{
    public:
        void enqueue(Heap<struct infoNode> x);
};

---
void QueueSpec::enqueue(Heap<struct infoNode> x) {}
```